# Why does the simpler oc statement take a longer time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, instruments

[image]

I am using Xcode Instruments Time Profiler to analyse some Objective-C code, and the statement `self.tbNavigationItem.tbNavibarRightItem = nil;` took a longer time than `self.tbNavigationItem.tbNavibarRightItem = [[TBBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:settingBtn];`, anyone can explain?

Comment: Perhaps deallocation of an existing object that was being referenced by the property?

Comment: 1) You need to profile over several hundred runs to even out the noise.  2) there may be weak references that need to be cleared.  3) you may be getting bad data due to the sampling frequency and bad luck.